# How to run jQuery function in input type text when input type text is in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Count; i++) {
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="text" required readonly name="emp[@i].Total_Marks" value="@ViewBag.Total" class="form-control" id="tm" /></td>
            <td> <input type="number" required name="emp[@i].Obtained_Marks" class="form-control" id="ob" /></td>
            <td> <input type="number" required name="emp[@i].Percentage" class="form-control" id="percentage" onfocus="calcper()" /></td>
            <td> <textarea cols="10" required rows="1" name="emp[@i].Remarks" class="form-control"></textarea></td>*
        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
function calculatePercentage() {
    ab = $("#tm").val();
    sb = $("#ob").val();
    ntb = parseInt(sb) / parseInt(ab) * 100;
    console.log(ntb);
    document.getElementById("percentage").value = ntb;
}
```

I am new to mvc 5 and javascript/jQuery please help me how can I use this jQuery function in percentage in every input type which is created by loop but their id is same

Comment: Create the input elements id dynamically by appending the loop index. Ideally we should not have duplicate id's in a HTML page.

Comment: this loop wil create multiple nodes of `<tbody></tbody>`

Comment: after you have created new HTML elements you need to "reassign" the DOM handlers. I prepared a `jsfiddle` which demonstrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/gfLn8mzj/6/

Comment: I did not get your answer please explain in deep

Answer (score 0):

As you said you need to call a function on your percentage textbox.
Let me tell you one thing assigning a same Id to a element is bad practice but you can have same name.
Recommend you to use common class attribute or common name attribute

```
<input type="text" name="percentage1" id="percentage1" class="percentage">
```

That you can consider as a empty class which will help you for your script operations
eg:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$('.percentage').keypress(function(){
    alert('I called');
});
</script>  
</head>  
 <BODY>
 <input type="text" name="percentage1" id="percentage1" class="percentage" />
 <input type="text" name="percentage2" id="percentage2" class="percentage"/>
 <input type="text" name="percentage3" id="percentage3" class="percentage"/>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In the above code I have three textbox where it is pointed to same function which will show alert box.

In your case just apply the emp[@i] to the Id also and have a common class name or have a common name attribute which will help you.

Happy coding.

Comment: maybe you could provide your code as a `snippet` for a better quality of the answer? You could also `alert()` something "element specific" to show that this is also possible :)

Comment: and this will also not work for dynamically generated elements: https://jsfiddle.net/gfLn8mzj/6/

Comment: @messerbill will surely follow your suggestions. "and this will also not work for dynamically generated elements" You have tried it using the javascipt as you might know, it  renders the element after the script and dom gets loaded. But the above code will work surely in MVC because the elements are rendered before script and it will take effect for every element. And I have answered keeping that in mind.

Comment: yes the code above will work, but it is not what the OT has asked for